# How to update mongo Object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to update my `mongo` Document following is my schema

```
{ "_id" : 7742, "current_count" : { "abc" : 6 } }
```

And need to update `current_count` object where i don't know the key and if the same key occurred need to **replace** the value as below.

```
{ "_id" : 7742, "current_count" : { "abc" : 6 ,"xyz":10} }
```

if `"abc"` encounters just need to replace it's value,

```
 { "_id" : 7742, "current_count" : { "abc" : 456 ,"xyz":10} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to loop over the keys which you getting as payload and need to create and set dynamic key value pair to `$set` operator

```
const data = {
  abc: 456,
  xyz: 10
}
const object = {}

for (var key in data) {
  object[`current_count.${key}`] = data[key]
}
```

Which would output as

```
current_count.abc: 456
current_count.xyz: 10
```

And then just put it in your query

```
const query = { "_id" : 7742 };
const update = { "$set": object };

await Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update)
```